# Change icon using jquery on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, font-awesome

Very new to jQuery, i'm trying to change the font icon class on click and display a drop down.  currently it changes the icon and drops down, but when i want it to toggle back the text toggles but the icon stays the same.  here is my code:

```
$(".answer1").hide();


$(".question1").on("click", function(){
    $(".answer1").toggle(300);
    $(this).find($(".fa")).removeClass('fa-plus').addClass('fa-minus');


});
```

any advice?

Comment: We need to see your HTML code to see what exactly you are trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seconds after posting i tried something and it worked, would this be ok to use? it does what i want it to:

```
$(".question1").on("click", function(){
    $(".answer1").toggle(300);
    $(this).find($(".fa")).toggleClass('fa-plus').toggleClass('fa-minus');


});
```

Comment: Yes. The problem in your original code was that you always set it to the same class fa-minus. By doing it this way it will toggle between them.

Comment: And also, it's ok to answer your own question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: `toggleClass()` can take more than one class.

Comment: @danko if i do that others wont benefit.  mardzis i did, none of the topics helped. thanks everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
   $(".question1").on("click", function(){
        $(".answer1").toggle(300);
        $(this).find($(".fa")).toggleClass('fa-plus fa-minus');

    });
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to test that to see what you meant: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y127rL92/